# How to run several Flask applications on the same server?

Tags: flask

I teach a course with over 40 students, who have to create Python web applications with Flask. I would like them to upload their applications to the department server (running Ubuntu). If all of them upload and run their apps, all except the first one will probably get an error that the port (5000 - the default port for Flask) is in use. I can ask each student to pick a random port number. But I would like the apps to be accessible using the students' names, so that, for example:

```
http://myserver.com/student1
```

would link to the application of student1.

Is there a way to do it, which can be done by the students themselves when they submit, so that I do not have to do manual work for each submission?

Comment: You could use nginx in front of student applications

Comment: I think it is not safe to let your students have free access to a server. They can create a very resource intensive loop, for example, that could crash or slow down your entire server. It will be more useful to them if they learn how to deploy their code into a free cloud server, like pythonanywhere: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask/

Comment: @EduardoMatsuoka The server is specifically dedicated to students' projects, so a crash will not cause harm to other systems. PythonAnywhere free plan is very limited - it gives only  512 MB disk space, and requires you to login every 3 months to keep the app alive.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to reverse proxy Unix sockets instead of using TCP ports and use the name of the student as the the actual socket name. For instance in NGINX each could be a location configuration which would make it easier to identify who's who.

```
server {
    listen 80 default;

    location /student1/ {
        proxy_pass http://student1/;
    }

    location /student2/ {
        proxy_pass http://student2/;
    }
}

upstream student1 {
    server unix:/home/ubuntu/student1;
}

upstream student1 {
    server unix:/home/ubuntu/student2;
}

...etc.
```

Comment: How would each student run Flask in this case? (Currently, each student chooses a port number and sends it to the Flask app).

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi The simplest way would be to pass the unix domain socket when starting Flask (the built-in development server) from the command line, such as FLASK_APP=app.py run --host=unix:///home/ubuntu/student1. A lot of it depends on the specific procedures used to start Flask on the particular environment, or if a WSGI server is used, as well as a process manager such as Supervisor. If using the unix socket approach, as opposed to a TCP port, it is important to ensure the web server process owner / group has read-write permissions on the socket itself, to avoid Bad Gateway errors.